# why redhat registration attach fails because of content access mode setting

Tags: rhel

I downloaded redhat and installed on nuc for demo purpose
i created redhat account and want to register this installation
all ok - upto subscription manager attach ..    because of content access mode
i followed all steps for unregister-clean - register.. but attach fails
at redhat user - simple content access is enabled
any idea how to resolve ?
many thanks, Regards, Guy